# Installing Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

[image: This is my GParted view.]

I want to install W10 (Windows 10) on `/dev/nvme0n1p3` (ntfs) formatting that 76.58GB of space. The system is UEFI and the partitioning scheme is most likely GPT. So what I intend to do is,

1. Boot to W10 from a live USB and install it on `/dev/nvme0n1p3` (now my machine should by default boot to W10)
2. Boot to Ubuntu 20.04 from a live USB
3. Setup GRUB menu (now my machine should provide me with an option to select an available OS while booting)

Is this safe? Or is there anything I should be careful of? As I don't want to lose any data. Also would you please elaborate on GRUB?

Note: My machine had W10 preinstalled. In the process of dual booting Ubuntu I had to remove W10 and install only Ubuntu 20.04. Then the system did not allow me to dual boot W10 in a step because of some partitioning issues.

Comment: Dual Boot advice: I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: If you don't want to lose data, then make backups. Repartitiong and installing a new Operating System is *inherently* unsafe.  Even if you think you are doing everything right, one typo or misunderstanding is all it takes.

Comment: Ubuntu is installed in Legacy mode. If the drive is actually GPT that would force Windows to be installed in UEFI mode and dual-boot with Grub would be impossible.